# Running DB::select in a config file

Tags: laravel

In my project we have a ".env" table so that the system admins can introduce api tokens for their services and we have a config file that gets it from the database:

```
return [
    'movidesk_api' => DB::select("SELECT MOVIDESK_API FROM SGN_ENV")[0],
    'movidesk_token' => DB::select("SELECT MOVIDESK_TOKEN FROM SGN_ENV")[0],
];
```

However after making this file all sort of errors pop up in Laravel's Handler file, and if this file is deleted there are no errors. Is running DB commands in a config file not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config is resolved very early in the bootstrap process, and before database connectivity is available. This has to be true since the database connection leans on config to find connection variables.

Since the information is stored in the database, a model seems like a more natural interface to the information than config().

Comment: Ah, makes sense, however I didn't really want to make a model since calling config(foo.bar) is easier than dependency injection and getting from model, but thanks for your help!